# Unable to use a regex to extract words: no method to_string for Match

Tags: regex, rust

I am trying to loop over a sentence and get the words using a regex:

```
use regex::Regex; // 1.0.6

fn example() {
    let re = Regex::new(r"\w+").unwrap();
    let sample_text = "This is me me.";
    for caps in re.captures_iter(&sample_text) {
        if let Some(cap) = caps.get(0) {
            let word = cap.to_string();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error.

```
error[E0599]: no method named `to_string` found for type `regex::re_unicode::Match<'_>` in the current scope
 --> src/lib.rs:8:28
  |
8 |             let word = cap.to_string();
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `to_string` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `regex::re_unicode::Match<'_> : std::string::ToString`
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You might also be interested in [`str::split_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace). This doesn't do the same as your code, but depending on what you want to achieve, it might be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

To get `&str` from the `Match` you can use this:

```
let my_str = cap.as_str(); // returns &str
```

If you really want to get a `String`, you can call `to_string()` on it:

```
let my_string = my_str.to_string(); // returns String
```

Also, you can take a look at the [`Match` documentation](https://docs.rs/regex/1.1.0/regex/struct.Match.html#method.as_str).

Comment: @joydeep bhattacharjee , if this is answer is exactly what you were asking for, could you please approve it as an answer to help the community